# Would the FAA's proposed Remote ID really ground older drones?

Tags: regulations, faa

The FAA has proposed new rules regarding drones, particularly [Remote ID](https://www.faa.gov/uas/research_development/remote_id/)

> Remote ID would assist the FAA, law enforcement, and Federal security agencies when a UAS appears to be flying in an unsafe manner or where the drone is not allowed to fly.
>
> The development of Remote ID builds on the framework established by the small UAS registration rule (PDF) and the LAANC capability to lay the foundation of an Unmanned Aircraft System Traffic Management System (UTM) that is scalable to the national airspace.

Criticism has [been harsh](https://dronelife.com/2020/01/14/not-like-this-djis-critical-response-to-faas-remote-id-proposal/)

> “Casual drone users would have to establish, maintain, and renew subscriptions just to fly occasionally in their backyards. School programs that use drones may decide the costs are just too high to continue. A gift of a drone on Christmas would saddle your recipient with endless monthly fees. And connecting all drones to the internet would create new cybersecurity vulnerabilities.”

Also

> And then there are the technical barriers to compliance. Schulman points out that “thousands of drones and radio-controlled aircraft currently on the market have no means for internet connection and would be grounded.”

Would this regulation really ground all existing drones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FPV Freedom Coalition has an excellent summary page [at this link](https://fpvfc.org/remote-id-nprm-faq).

To sum up the answer to your question as simply as I understand it: older drones that are not able to broadcast their information will **NOT** be grounded, however they will be required to only fly within **FRIAs** (FAA Recognised Identification Areas).

Under the current proposal, after one year no new FRIAs may be registered, so as they disappear over time it may become more difficult to legally fly non-compliant aircraft.

I am not a legal expert - if anyone feels my understanding is incorrect then please do let me know.

Comment: I believe this to be incorrect. There are two paths to (non-exempt) compliance: "standard" remote ID ([89.110](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-89/subpart-B/section-89.110)) and "alternate" (module) remote ID ([89.115](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-89/subpart-B/section-89.115)). There are several exemption paths, but if those exemption paths do not apply then legacy aircraft are - I believe - expected to equip with velcro-on modules.

Comment: Also worth noting that your original answer was in 2020, and operator compliance will be enforced as of Sept 2023. Between those two dates there has been some refinement of the law.